# 1996 ford courier 2.6 petrol duel cab

Tags: ford, clutch

My clutch started sticking to the floor and then it went completely I've replaced the slave cylinder and bleed the clutch but it still seems to stick it got a little better after the bleed but after 5-10 mins it's back on the floor again

Comment: Did you check the line for leaks? Did you test the clutch master cylinder?

Comment: When you say "sticking", does it feel like something is jammed, or does the pedal just feel soft and easy to press down?

Comment: I push the peddle and it sucks it's self back to the floor

Answer (score 2):

Frequently with clutches it's very hard to bleed the air out.  You can sit with a partner in the cabin of the vehicle and do this forever and never get all the air out.

I recommend you get a hand vacuum pump to bleed brakes and hydraulic clutches.

This is what they look like.

[image]

You attach a clear tube to the bleed nipple of the clutch master cylinder and put the catch container in line with that and the hand pump.

You don't need a partner to assist when you do this.  As well, you can see air coming out of the clear tubing so you get rewarded as your hand get's tired.  Be sure to keep fluid going into the fill for the clutch, if you go empty, you start to pull air in and your at square one.

If your in the states you can goto Harbor Freight and get these for under $20 US.  They are will worth every penny.

If you find you still have an issue after pulling out all of the air at least you know what it isn't and can rule that out before you start procuring more parts.  I see this as essential to success when bleeding brakes and clutches.

Best of luck, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that the pedal is sucked to the floor, the only thing that could be causing this is a fault in the brake booster (servo).  The booster uses vacuum from the engine to assist pressure from your foot when pressing the brake.  If there is a fault in the valve mechanism inside the booster, then the vacuum from the engine will keep assisting until the pedal hits the floor as you describe.  Presumably this only happens when the engine is running.  If you turn the engine off, does the pedal rise again?